# Extract all urls Href php

Tags: php, dom, hyperlink, extract, href

I have an HTML with many links. I am currently able to get links, just all over, I would only get a certain word.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

I would list only links that contained a certain word,
example: sendspace.com

result would be more or less below the:
http://www.fileserve.com/file/eDpDMm9sad/
http://www.fileserve.com/file/7s83hjh347/

I would then convert these links to sha1.

after conversion to save the html sha1 already applied to the links with the words contained.

Comment: I would list only links that contained a certain word, example: fileserve.com

Answer (score 2):

Using [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), you can traverse the DOM and find the anchors (`<a>`) with the `href` attribute containing what you want:

```
$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($htmlSource);
$anchors = $dom->find('a[href|=sendspace.com]');

$urls = array();

if($anchors) {
  foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $anchor = pq($anchor);
    $urls[] = $anchor->attr('href');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match your word (or whatever else) in the string like so:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (preg_match("/example\.com/i", $link->getAttribute('href'))) {
        // do things here!
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I convert these links to sha1? and then return to the html already applied with sha1

Comment: You can hash it with sha1 by using this function: sha1($thingyouwanttohashtosha1);