# PHP: get only part of a match from a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get some URL's from a webpage using PHP regular expressions.

I'm doing this:

```
preg_match_all('/"r"><a href="http:.*?"/i',$Rec_Data, $stuff );
```

This works in returning the url's however I also get code I don't want:

```
"r"><a href="http://www.cbsnews.com/stories/2002/12/03/politics/main531460.shtml"
```

I can't get rid of the "r" and the "a" tag. I need it so I don't match URL's I don't want. How do I get only the part that is matched by ".*?" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract all urls Href php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262682/extract-all-urls-href-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for grabbing the href attribute of an a element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783)

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_match all a href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519696/preg-match-all-a-href)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and use the second element in the result:

```
preg_match_all('/"r"><a href="(http:.*?)"/i',$Rec_Data, $stuff );
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZKQWs)

Also, you might want to consider using an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662) to parse HTML, instead of a regular expression.

Comment: @SrgHartman: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I posted a link to an online demo where you can see that it works...

Comment: @MarkByers: my bad, it actually works. However I get two arrays. That looks like a waste of resources. Is it possible to get the regex engine to return only the match I want?